# Bash/shell/OS interpretation of . and .. — can I define ...?

Tags: bash, shell, operating-system, kernel, posix

How do `.` and `..`, as paths (vs. ranges, e.g., `{1..10}`, which I'm not concerned with), really work? I know what they do, and use them all the time, but don't fully grasp how/where they're interpreted. Does the shell handle them? The interpreting process? The OS?

The reason why I'm asking is that I'd like to be able to use `...` to refer to `../..`, `....` to refer to `../../..`, etc. (up to some small finite number; I don't need bash to process an arbitrarily large number of dots). I.e., if my current directory is `/tmp/let/me/out`, and I call `cd ...`, my resulting current directory should be `/tmp/let`. I don't particularly care if `...` etc. show up in `ls -a` output like `.` and `..` do, but I would like to be able to call `cat /tmp/let/me/out/..../phew.txt` to print the contents of `/tmp/phew.txt`.

Pointers to relevant documentation appreciated as well as direct answers. This kind of syntax question is very hard to Google.

I'm using `bash 4.3.42`, by the way, with the `autocd` and `globstar` shell options.

Answer (score 3):

`.` and `..` are genuine directory names. They are not "sort-cuts", aliases, or anything fake.

They happen to point to the same [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) as the other name you use. A file or directory can have several names pointing to the same [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode), these are usually known as hard links, to distinguish them from symbolic (or soft) links.

If you are on Linux or OS X you can use `stat` to look at most of the inode metadata - it is what `ls` looks at.  You will see there is an inode number.  If you `stat .` and `stat current-directory-name` you will see that number is the same.

The one thing that is not held in the inode is the filename - that is held in the directory.

So `.` and `..` reside in the directory on the file system, they are not a figment of the shell's imagination.   So, for example, I can use `.` and `..` quite happily from C.

I doubt you can change them - personally I have never tried and I never will.  You would have to change what these filenames linked to by editing the directory.  If you managed it you would probably do irreparable damage to your file system.

Answer (score 1):

I write this to clarify what has already been written before.

In many file systems a DIRECTORY is a file; a special type of file that the file system identifies as being distinctly a directly.

A directory file contains a list of names that map to files on the disk

A file, including a directly does not have an intrinsic name associated with it (not true in all file systems). The name of a file exists only in a directory.

The same file can have an entry in multiple directories (hard link). The same file can then have multiple names and multiple paths.

The file system maintains in every directory entries for "`.`" and "`..`"

In such file systems there are always directory ENTRIES for the NAMES "`.`" and "`..`". These entries are maintained by the file system.

The name "`.`" links to its own directory.
The name "`..`" links to the parent directory EXCEPT for the top level directory where it links to itself (`.` and `..` thus link to the same directory file).

So when you use "`.`" and "`..`" as in /dir1/dir2/../dir3/./dir4/whatever, 
"`.`" and "`..`" are processed in the exact same way as "dir1" and "dir2".

This translation is done by the file system; not the shell.

```
cd ...
```

Does not work because there is no entry for "`...`" (at least not normally).

You can create a directory called "`...`" if you want.

Comment: You could also do `ln -s ../.. ...; ln -s ../../.. ....`.  And the file system wouldn't have to worry about 'maintaining them', even if the directories were moved around.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It would be good to note, however, that these two symlinks would have to be created in _every_ directory where the OP wanted them to work - creating them in one directory would not automatically make them available everywhere...

Answer (score 1):

You can actually achieve something like this, though **this is an ugly hack**:

You can run a command before every command entered to bash, and after every command. For that you `trap` the `DEBUG` pseudo signal and set a command to `PROMPT_COMMAND`, respectively.

```
trap 'ln -s ../.. ... &>/dev/null | true' DEBUG
PROMPT_COMMAND='rm ...'
```

With this, it *seems* like there's an additional entry in the *current* directory:

```
pwd
# /tmp/crazy-stuff
ls -a
# . .. ... foo
ls -a .../tmp/crazy-stuff
# . .. ... foo
```

Though this only works in the current directory, because the symbolic links is deleted after each command invokation. Thus `ls foo/bar/...` **won't** work this way.

Another ugly hack would be to "override" `mkdir` such that it populates every new directory with these symbolic links.

Comment: I think this is closest to my desired goal so far, but I see now that if I want proper `..`-like functionality with `...`, it would have to be just as ingrained into my filesystem as `.` and `..` are, i.e., as actual children of every single directory. That makes overriding (or even redefining, e.g., https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/ext4/namei.c#L2555) `mkdir` seem like not only an ugly hack, but the right way, considering the perversity of my request.

Comment: If you're mostly using the command line, then you could make mkdir an alias for some function that calls the real mkdir and creates the links. Or you could (additionally) have some tool that (periodically) traverses the filesystem and adds these links. Or perhaps you can use inotify to watch for directories created and then add the links. Endless possibilities, if you want to realize this "perversity" :)

Answer (score 0):

See also the comments on the second answer here, particularly Eliah's: https://askubuntu.com/questions/327126/what-is-a-dot-only-named-folder

Much in the same way that when you `cd` into some directory `subdir`, you're actually following a pointer that points to that directory, `..` is a pointer added by the OS that points to the parent directory, and I'd imagine `.` works the same way.

Comment: On most file systems, `.`, and `..` are not merely an "OS-implemented aliases", but are actual directory entries created by the file system code as the first two entries in any newly created directory during the `mkdir()` system call.

Comment: @twalberg My apologies, by alias I meant in the sense of desktop shortcut or directory pointer, as on the OSX desktop. Poor choice of words. Is this better?

Comment: @Cameron:  no, they are not short-cuts in that sense either.  The analogy would only fit if they were symbolic links, but these are hard links.

Comment: @twalberg: As far as I know, on Linux (which is most suitable for tag `bash`) directory entries `.` and `..` are actually implemented by OS, and they are transparent for concrete file system implementation. So the answer is correct for that OS.